Mathematical and Intuitive understanding of "Optimal Substructure"
Wikipedia formally puts the definition of optimal substructure as below:
"A slightly more formal definition of optimal substructure can be given. Let a "problem" be a collection of "alternatives", and let each alternative have an associated cost, c(a). The task is to find a set of alternatives that minimizes c(a). Suppose that the alternatives can be partitioned into subsets, i.e. each alternative belongs to only one subset. Suppose each subset has its own cost function. The minima of each of these cost functions can be found, as can the minima of the global cost function, restricted to the same subsets. If these minima match for each subset, then it's almost obvious that a global minimum can be picked not out of the full set of alternatives, but out of only the set that consists of the minima of the smaller, local cost functions we have defined. If minimizing the local functions is a problem of "lower order", and (specifically) if, after a finite number of these reductions, the problem becomes trivial, then the problem has an optimal substructure."
I have trouble understanding this and relating this aspect to the more standard put-forth definition of Optimal Substructure as, "Optimal Solution to the problem can be constructued from considering optimal solutions to its subproblems".
I am trying to understand what it means for a problem to have optimal substructure, and understanding these definitions is not helping me get anywhere. The wikipedia definition also says "...and let each alternative have an associated cost, c(a). The task is to find a set of alternatives that minimizes c(a)", where I absolutely do not understand how c(a) which was previously said to be related to a single alternative; now is related to a "set" of alternatives? What is the problem? What even is an alternative?
I tried taking an example to clarify this, and this is what I came up with:
Say we have a starting source "A", and we need to reach "D" in a graph in the lowest cost possible. An "alternative" is a single connection between any two immediate cities. For us to have a notion of alternatives belonging to a single subset, I thought of having all the connections moving out of my current city (out-degree of a node) as something that I can relate to. The cities (alternatives) that are immediately reachable from a node, those are grouped under the same subset. I named it as "subset {node they came from}".
Now according to my understanding of the explanation, we find the local optima (immediately reachable node with the lowest cost. This does NOT have to be the path that is in the lowest cost path) by being at every subset.
For the second part, we now stand at each subset and find the lowest path that leads to the destination "D" from this subset's start. This has to be the "lowest next hop that also leads to our destination D". The immediate path from this subset node 'x', is the alternative that leads to the lowest possible route from 'x' to "D". I think, now the explanation asks us to compare these routes. If they match for the locally optimal case, as well as the globally optimal case, then we have optimal substrucuture? Is my interpretation right? I don't think so, because it seems to be very much related to greedy behaviour, as opposed to dynamic programming. But I really have no clue, which is why it has been bugging me.
It would be really helpful to understand what is this optimal substructure property that a problem has, and how one can identify it. Thanks!
I understand that the example that I considered above is very restrictive, and inherently brings along with it the notion of "subsets" (as a single node). I hope to have that clarified, generalised too; if that is indeed possible.

IMO, the opening section of that WP article is spot on.  The part you quote, not only is really not more than a vague sketch, it indeed arguably and most notably just conflates "problem(s)" with "solution(s)"...

@JulioDiEgidio, I initially came to that exact conclusion (WK's opening article). As in, I was convincing myself saying that the Optimal Substructure is basically a property of a problem in which, if you're solving a bigger chunk of it, it helps to know what the optimal answer for the smaller chunks are. The recursion allows us to nicely distribute the bigger problem to a smaller one(s). But the more I think about it, I think there has to be something different. Perhaps I'm overthinking, but I really hope to have it cleared.

Actually, to be clear, the point was the optimal substructure is about the structure of the solution(s).  --  As said, (IMO) the opening section of that article is rather more precise, while the "formal" part is simply wrong, and not just in the choice of names.
